# Get data from a nested span element

Tags: javascript

I want to make platform to learn CSS kind of like code-academy, I want to have some client-side code validation. Using codemirror I managed to do a codepen-like app and now I want to implement the validation. My Idea was to use take advantage of the editor format to create an object and then compare that object with one of my own with the correct answer.

For example:

This is what the user puts on the editor:

```
.container {
  /* Your code goes here */
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Each of those lines translate to the following

```
<span class="cm-qualifier">.container</span> {

&nbsp;<span class="cm-comment">/* Your code goes here */</span>

&nbsp;<span class="cm-property">padding</span>: <span class="cm-number">10px</span>;

&nbsp;<span class="cm-property">display</span>: <span class="cm-atom">flex</span>;

&nbsp;<span class="cm-property">justify-content</span>: <span class="cm-atom">center</span>;

&nbsp;<span class="cm-property">align-items</span>: <span class="cm-atom">center</span>;

}
```

With javascript I would like to get the text line by line, my problem is that I don't know how to get the value from inside the span tag and outside of it.

This is what I did to get that working.

```
let data;
window.onload = function() {
  dataBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.CodeMirror-lines')[0];
  data = dataBlock.querySelectorAll("span[role='presentation']");

  let dataArr = Array.from(data).map(x => {
    console.log(x.innerHTML);
  });
}
```

I have one idea, to split the innerHTML from  the character '<' to the character '>' and so on. But I believe there should be a better approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can access the raw input text and line numbers in codemirror api  without having to parse the html to reverse engineer it

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit, I'm not sure I understand what you said.

Comment: Your CodeMirror instance has a `getLine(n: integer)` method. https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getLine